# iOS Core Audio: How can I get output time of buffer passed throug Audio Processing Tap?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, core-audio

I use an `AVPlayer` to output sound & visualization of it. My problem is that visualization of a chunk of sound is time-shifted and occurs before user hears that chunk. This is because of bufferization.

New audio buffer is played ~0.2 seconds later than it is processed (I suppose there's 3 total buffers in my case).

My visualization is occurred immediately after processing. So sound & visualisation is not synchronous.

It looks quite ugly. I know I can hardcode these 0.2 seconds delay (2*4096/44100 seconds exactly), but this will be a kludge. Also my bluetooth speakers have much higher delay (about 0.5-1.0 seconds).

I want to know how to determine the delay of bufferization, Or if it's even possible on iOS. (Refusing Core Audio or `AVPlayer` is an option, but it's not desirable).

I can get audio via `MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio`:

```
OSStatus MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio(
        MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap,
        CMItemCount numberFrames,
        AudioBufferList *bufferListInOut,
        MTAudioProcessingTapFlags *flagsOut,
        CMTimeRange *timeRangeOut,
        CMItemCount *numberFramesOut);
```

Inside a `MTAudioProcessingTapProcessCallback`:

```
 typedef void (*MTAudioProcessingTapProcessCallback)(
        MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap,
        CMItemCount numberFrames,
        MTAudioProcessingTapFlags flags,
        AudioBufferList *bufferListInOut,
        CMItemCount *numberFramesOut,
        MTAudioProcessingTapFlags *flagsOut);
```

I can get offset of audio buffer via "timeRangeOut" variable. It is when audio buffer appears in track. But I don't know when the buffer will be heard by user.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm trying now AudioSessionAddPropertyListener(kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareIOBufferDuration, <#callback#>, (__bridge void *)self); and AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareIOBufferDuration, &size, &bufferDuration);

Comment: I didn't try actually. I wrote the code but didn't test it with bluetooth speakers and I don't work on that project now. So I don't know. You can log (NSLog) the difference between current time and output time. If there would be a difference between different outputs (bluetooth/internal speaker) then use it. Try. And good luck.